# Get headers sent through postman in java

Tags: java, rest, cxf, postman

I am exposing my java application as REST api using apache cxf.

How can I get the header details sent by api caller in my java application @GET method

Comment: And what have you tried? Show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache CXF implements the JAX-RS specification. So you can inject [`HttpHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) in your resource class or resource methods using [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html):

```java
@Context
HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
```

Then you can use the [`HttpHeaders` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#method.summary) to get the header values:

- [`HttpHeaders#getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getHeaderString-java.lang.String-)
- [`HttpHeaders#getRequestHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeaders--)
- [`HttpHeaders#getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeader-java.lang.String-)

If you need the value of a standard HTTP header, consider using the [constants available in the `HttpHeaders` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#field.summary):

```java
// Get the value of the Authorization header
String authorizationHeader = httpHeaders.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```

---

See the Apache CXF [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Contextannotations) about context types for further details.

Comment: Thanks Cássio, it solved my issue.

[link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxrs_contextobjects_httpheaders.html) also explains the same with examples

Comment: Cassio,
How can I remove below error:

_Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._

I get this error when I access the API from an html file

Comment: @user8765332 It's a CORS issue. You should ask another question.

Comment: I asked already here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200530/access-control-allow-origin-in-apache-cxf)

No clear answers